# Vim Javascript Indentation Inside A Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vim, macvim

I've been using MacVim for my main editor for a while now. I mainly use it for javascript, express.js to be specific, and one thing that is bothering me is the indentation of it.

I want the indentation to do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello, world!");  
});
```

But right now it's doing this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send("Hello, world!");
            });
```

I don't know why it's doing this. And for extra information, this is my .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set tabstop=4
set smartindent
set autoindent
```

I also have [this](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) installed via Pathogen. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `vimrc`.

Comment: What is the filetype or file extension.  Are you sure the editor knows it is a Javascript file?

Comment: Thank you @dNitro! The problem is now fixed after I added `filetype plugin indent` to my vimrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `vimrc`.